# Can I create empty, self-closing tags in RSS feed generated by django with python 2.7?

Tags: xml, django, python-2.7, rss, syndication-feed

## I would like

To create an RSS feed using django, including self-closing tags like

`<tag key="value"/>`

## Current set up

I'm building an RSS feed using django's [`SimplerXMLGenerator`](http://fossies.org/dox/Django-1.7.5/classdjango_1_1utils_1_1xmlutils_1_1SimplerXMLGenerator.html). This is basically just python's `XMLGenerator` with one handy function added.

```
"""
Utilities for XML generation/parsing.
"""

from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator

class SimplerXMLGenerator(XMLGenerator):
    def addQuickElement(self, name, contents=None, attrs=None):
        "Convenience method for adding an element with no children"
        if attrs is None: attrs = {}
        self.startElement(name, attrs)
        if contents is not None:
            self.characters(contents)
        self.endElement(name)
```

From the [XMLGenerator docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator):

> `class xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator(out=None, encoding='iso-8859-1',
>   short_empty_elements=False)`
>
> This class implements the [ContentHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler) interface by writing SAX
>   events back into an XML document
>
> "New in [python] version 3.2: The short_empty_elements parameter."

If `short_empty_elements=True`, then output for a tag with attr's but no content becomes
`<tag attr="value"/>`
i.e., a short, self-closing tag
rather than separate opening and closing tags like this
`<tag attr="value"></tag>`

However, I'm using python 2.7, so don't have the option to set `short_empty_elements=True` (that keyword is not recognized)

Specifically, I'm generating the feed using django's [Rss201rev2Feed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#rss201rev2feed) (itself a subclass of [SyndicationFeed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.feedgenerator.SyndicationFeed)

Tags are added via the ContentHandler
`handler = SimplerXMLGenerator(outfile, encoding)`
Currently if I add an "empty" tag with

`handler.addQuickElement("tag", "", {"attr": "value"})`

the results is

```
<tag attr="value"></tag>
```

whereas I would like

```
<tag attr="value"/>
```

Anybody know I way I can set the feed to render these short, empty, self-closing tags, while on python 2.7?

Comment: I don't know if there is an existing library, but you can subclass `XMLGenerator` to backport that feature and write your own `addQuickElement` method that uses the new class.

Comment: Sounds appealing -- can I beg for any hint for code you might suggest? Currently the SimplerXMLGenerator subclasses XMLGenerator to use its existing startElement and endElement functions, which perform opening and closing tags as separate tasks.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.startElement How would I get around this?